# Store value and reaccess from the memory location in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, shared-memory

say I store

```
a=9
```

in a program. the value of a is stored in the computer memory.
By making no changes in the memory if I want to re-access the memory location and print its content.
How do I do that in python.

I want to take the memory address from first program and in the new one use that memory address and print its value.

I tried using ctype to access the memory locations but i end up getting segmentation fault.

Comment: How are you running those two programs?

Comment: You can't normally do that sort of thing on a modern OS as each process runs in its own protected memory space, both for security reasons and to prevent faulty programs from clobbering the RAM used by other processes. Also, Python's data model doesn't really encourage manipulating stuff at the memory address level. In standard Python (aka CPython) the `id` of an object is its memory address, but that's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the value between two Python processes have a look at the [`multiprocessing` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and its tools for sharing values.